# Spring Batch Admin not working with Spring Integration 2.1

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-integration, spring-batch-admin

I have an existing Web application using Spring Integration 2.1.0 and Spring Batch 2.2.7.

I want to add Spring Batch Admin embedded in this existing Web app, but I can't make it work.

When I try to use the current Spring Batch Admin release (1.2.1), I get the following error.

> SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener
>   instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListe
>   ner org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefi
>   nitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean
>   definitions from URL location
>   [classpath*:/META-INF/spring/batch/bootstrap/**/*.xml]
>
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefi
>   nitionParsingException: Configuration problem: You cannot use prior
>   versions of Spring Integration schemas with Spring Integration 2.1.
>   Please upgrade your schema declarations or use versionless aliases
>   (e.g. spring-integration.xsd).

Since I don't want to downgrade my Spring Integration version, I've tried to used the 1.3.0.M1 (milestone) version of Spring Batch Admin. Then again, I get what seems to be another "Spring Integration mismatched versions problem"...

> SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefi
>   nitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean
>   definitions from URL location
>   [classpath*:/META-INF/spring/batch/servlet/manager/*.xml] Offending
>   resource: ServletContext resource
>   [/WEB-INF/spring/batch-admin/batch-admin-context.xml]; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefin
>   itionStoreException: Line 372 in XML document from URL
>   [jar:file:/D:/axon-sevl/workspace-git/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/sii-web/WEB-INF/lib/spring-batch-admin-manager-1.3.0.M1.jar!/META-INF/spring/batch/servlet/manager/integration-context.xml]
>   is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;
>   systemId: http://www.springframework.org/schem...tion-http.xsd;
>   lineNumber: 372; columnNumber: 119; src-resolve: Cannot resolve the
>   name 'integration:adviceChainType' to a(n) 'type definition'
>   component.

Is there anyone who managed to make it work or do I absolutely have to change the Spring Integration version I'm currently using?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Spring Integration 2.1 is a **very** old version of Spring Integration (they just released version 4).  You'll need to upgrade your version to get it working.

Comment: I don't see any versioned schemas anywhere in s-b-a production code - just in `JmsIntgrationTests-context.xml` (which should be fixed, but shouldn't affect runtime). This error (the first one) implies there is a versioned schema there. We generally recommend not putting versions in the `schemaLocation` to avoid this issue.

Comment: The first error (using S.B.A. 1.2.1) seems to be a known issue... https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCHADM-125

Comment: spring batch admin still uses very old version of spring integration 2.2.5.RELEASE. So not able to upgrade to latest spring integration version https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch-admin/blob/master/spring-batch-admin-parent/pom.xml